# Summary Tables using Nested Tibbles

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I am trying to generate a table of summary statistics using `purrr`/`tibble` methods.  I am able to calculate group-wise mean (sd) and counts using the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

mtcars %>%
  gather(variable, value, -vs, -am) %>%
  group_by(vs, am, variable) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("mpg", "hp")) %>% 
  mutate(
    mean = map_dbl(data, ~mean(.$value, na.rm = TRUE)),
    sd = map_dbl(data, ~sd(.$value, na.rm = TRUE)),
    n = map_dbl(data, ~sum(!is.na(.$value)))
  )  %>% 
  select(vs:variable, mean:n) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(mean, sd), round, 3) %>% 
  mutate(mean_sd = paste0(mean, " (", sd, ")"),
         var_group = paste(vs, am, variable, sep = "_")) %>% 
  select(n:var_group) %>%
  nest(n, mean_sd, .key = "summary") %>% 
  spread(key = var_group, value = summary) %>% 
  unnest()
```

My immediate question is, how do I retain the column names as seen in `spread(key = var_group, value = summary)` in the `unnest()`-ed output?

edit: Thanks to all for the responses.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55912326/5745045 has the advantages of being easier to read and not storing a temporary variable.  A disadvantage is the change of numeric to character in the `n` columns.

The final goal is to replace the column names with formatted text within the context of a grouped `kable` table.

Comment: If you look at each column, it is a `tibble` with its own column names.  So, not sure what you intend as expected output

Comment: Perhaps after the `spread` step `%>% gather %>% unnest %>% gather(key1, val, n, mean_sd) %>% unite(key, key, key1) %>% spread(key, val) %>% retype` `library(hablar)`

Comment: Or another option would be `%>% imap_dfc(., ~ {nm1 <- .y; .x %>% pluck(1) %>% rename_all(~ str_c(.x, "_", nm1))})`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I will clarify in the question.  The intended output would be column names with group labels appended: `0_0_hp_n` and `0_0_hp_mean_sd` and so on.  Further, if this is not the canonical approach to summaries using nested tibbles, any alternative is welcome as well.

Comment: IN that case, the commented ones should work

Comment: @akrun I can get the first one to work but ```%>% imap_dfc(., ~ {nm1 <- .y; .x %>% pluck(1) %>% rename_all(~ str_c(.x, "_", nm1))})``` throws this error: ```Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"``` ... Would you post an answer? I am very much interested in your explanation about these solutions and specifically your line of thoughts towards forming them up. Cheers.

Comment: @M-M  Could that be due to some package version `packageVersion("purrr")
#[1] ‘0.3.0’`

Comment: @akrun could be ... ```packageVersion("purrr") ##[1] ‘0.3.2’```

Comment: so yours is a newer one, may be some things changed as usual with tidyverse

Comment: @akrun it's very much plausible. Tried going back to `0.3.0` but dependencies cannot be installed. Anyhow, thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another method that doesn't require creating a temporary variable. Instead of nesting the data at the end, I used `gather()` and `unite()` to restructure the data so that it ends up as one key and value pair.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
#>   method         from 
#>   [.quosures     rlang
#>   c.quosures     rlang
#>   print.quosures rlang
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'rvest':
#>   method            from
#>   read_xml.response xml2
mtcars %>%
  gather(variable, value, -vs, -am) %>%
  group_by(vs, am, variable) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("mpg", "hp")) %>% 
  mutate(
    mean = map_dbl(data, ~mean(.$value, na.rm = TRUE)),
    sd = map_dbl(data, ~sd(.$value, na.rm = TRUE)),
    n = map_dbl(data, ~sum(!is.na(.$value)))
  )  %>% 
  select(vs:variable, mean:n) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(mean, sd), round, 3) %>% 
  mutate(mean_sd = paste0(mean, " (", sd, ")"),
         var_group = paste(vs, am, variable, sep = "_")) %>% 
  select(n:var_group) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -var_group) %>% 
  unite(var_group_key, var_group, key) %>% 
  spread(var_group_key, value)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 16
#>   `0_0_hp_mean_sd` `0_0_hp_n` `0_0_mpg_mean_s… `0_0_mpg_n` `0_1_hp_mean_sd`
#>   <chr>            <chr>      <chr>            <chr>       <chr>           
#> 1 194.167 (33.36)  12         15.05 (2.774)    12          180.833 (98.816)
#> # … with 11 more variables: `0_1_hp_n` <chr>, `0_1_mpg_mean_sd` <chr>,
#> #   `0_1_mpg_n` <chr>, `1_0_hp_mean_sd` <chr>, `1_0_hp_n` <chr>,
#> #   `1_0_mpg_mean_sd` <chr>, `1_0_mpg_n` <chr>, `1_1_hp_mean_sd` <chr>,
#> #   `1_1_hp_n` <chr>, `1_1_mpg_mean_sd` <chr>, `1_1_mpg_n` <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

By storing the *"nested"* `tibble` as a temporary variable<sup>1</sup> and using its `colnames`<sup>2</sup>, we can achieve what you desire. Look below;

```
mtcars %>%
  gather(variable, value, -vs, -am) %>%
  group_by(vs, am, variable) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("mpg", "hp")) %>% 
  mutate(
    mean = map_dbl(data, ~mean(.$value, na.rm = TRUE)),
    sd = map_dbl(data, ~sd(.$value, na.rm = TRUE)),
    n = map_dbl(data, ~sum(!is.na(.$value)))
  )  %>% 
  select(vs:variable, mean:n) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(mean, sd), round, 3) %>% 
  mutate(mean_sd = paste0(mean, " (", sd, ")"),
         var_group = paste(vs, am, variable, sep = "_")) %>% 
  select(n:var_group) %>%
  nest(n, mean_sd, .key = "summary") %>% 
  spread(key = var_group, value = summary) %>% 
  #1: storing the temporary nested variable
  {. ->> temptibble} %>%
  unnest() %>% 
  #2: renaming the columns of unnested output and removing temporary variable
  rename_all(funs(paste0(., "_", rep(colnames(temptibble), each=2)))); rm(temptibble)
```

```
# # A tibble: 1 x 16
#   n_0_0_hp   mean_sd_0_0_hp  n1_0_0_mpg  mean_sd1_0_0_mpg  n2_0_1_hp  mean_sd2_0_1_hp n3_0_1_mpg  mean_sd3_0_1_mpg
#   <dbl>      <chr>                <dbl>  <chr>                 <dbl>  <chr>                <dbl>  <chr>                
# 1       12  194.167 (33.36)          12     15.05 (2.774)          6 180.833 (98.816)          6     19.75 (4.009)
#    n4_1_0_hp   mean_sd4_1_0_hp n5_1_0_mpg  mean_sd5_1_0_mpg   n6_1_1_hp  mean_sd6_1_1_hp  n7_1_1_mpg  mean_sd7_1_1_mpg
#        <dbl>   <chr>                <dbl>  <chr>                  <dbl>  <chr>                 <dbl>  <chr>
# 1         7   102.143 (20.932)         7     20.743 (2.471)           7  80.571 (24.144)           7    28.371 (4.758)
```